# Execution with more than one machine failed

Tags: c++, boost, graph, mpi, qsub

related to my work (here [Using a generic type with an adjacency_list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5860801/using-a-generic-type-with-an-adjacency-list)) I'm now testing the execution of a simple code that does the following:

- Initializes the boost-mpi enviroment
- Load a graph from a file into a distributed adjacency_list
- Finnally performs 2 simple operations over it in each machine: count the number of edges and calculates the clustering coefficient.

Here's the code:

```
#include "Common.h"
#include "GraphFileReader.h"
#include "GraphNeighbors.h"
#include <boost/graph/metis.hpp>
#include <boost/mpi/environment.hpp>
#include <boost/mpi/communicator.hpp>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv []){

    // Start mpi enviroment
    boost::mpi::environment env(argc, argv);
    boost::mpi::communicator world;

    // Create the graph
    GraphFileReader *graphFileReader;
    undirectedAdjacencyList graph;

    if(process_id(graph.process_group()) == 0){
            // Load the graph's path
            graphFileReader = new GraphFileReader(argv[1]);
            // Read the graph file and adds the vertices and edges
            graphFileReader->loadGraph(graph);
    }

    // Wait until the process 0 has finished loading the graph
    world.barrier();
    synchronize(graph.process_group());

    GraphNeighbors graphNeighbors;

    // Now each machine should process it's own graph piece
    graphNeighbors.countEdges(graph);
    graphNeighbors.clusteringCoefficient(graph);

    // Wait for the other processes before finishing
    world.barrier();
    synchronize(graph.process_group());
    cout << "\n process: " << world.rank() <<" finishing\n" << std::endl;
```

And here's the result:

```
graphs: /usr/include/boost/graph/distributed/adjacency_list.hpp:2679: 
std::pair<typename boost::adjacency_list<OutEdgeListS, boost::distributedS<ProcessGroup, 
InVertexListS, InDistribution>, DirectedS, VertexProperty, EdgeProperty, GraphProperty,
 EdgeListS>::out_edge_iterator, typename boost::adjacency_list<OutEdgeListS, 
boost::distributedS<ProcessGroup, InVertexListS, InDistribution>, DirectedS, 
VertexProperty, EdgeProperty, GraphProperty, EdgeListS>::out_edge_iterator> 
boost::out_edges(typename boost::adjacency_list<OutEdgeListS, 
boost::distributedS<ProcessGroup, InVertexListS, InDistribution>, DirectedS, 
VertexProperty, EdgeProperty, GraphProperty, EdgeListS>::vertex_descriptor, const 
boost::adjacency_list<OutEdgeListS, boost::distributedS<ProcessGroup, InVertexListS, 
InDistribution>, DirectedS, VertexProperty, EdgeProperty, GraphProperty, EdgeListS>&) [with
 OutEdgeListS = boost::vecS, ProcessGroup = boost::graph::distributed::mpi_process_group,
 InVertexListS = boost::vecS, InDistribution = boost::defaultS, DirectedS = 
boost::undirectedS, VertexProperty = Node, EdgeProperty = boost::no_property, GraphProperty
= boost::no_property, EdgeListS = boost::listS]: Assertion `v.owner == g.processor()' failed.

_________________________________________________________________

I'm process: 0    
I'm process: 1

Number of edges: 4
        0.37694 milliseconds
Number of edges: 2
        0.16284 milliseconds
rank 1 in job 1  compute-1-4_49342   caused collective abort of all ranks
  exit status of rank 1: killed by signal 6
_________________________________________________________________
Epilogue Args:
Job  ID:        138573.tucan
User ID:        ***
Group ID:       ***
Job Name:       mpiGraphs.job
Resource List:  5746
Queue Name:     ncpus=1,neednodes=2:ppn=2,nodes=2:ppn=2
Account String: cput=00:00:00,mem=420kb,vmem=13444kb,walltime=00:00:02
Date:           Thu Mar  1 14:28:19 CET 2012
_________________________________________________________________
```

On the other hand, the execution with only one machine works perfectly:

```
I'm process: 0

Number of edges: 6
        8.46696 milliseconds
The network average clustering coefficient is: 0.53333
        0.12708 milliseconds


 process: 0 finishing
```

My tutor and I thought that this could be because one machine ends while the other is still performing it's operations, so we add the synchronize and the barrier (I actually don't know the difference between both, so I tested a few combinations with same results).

If you need the rest of the code (Common.h, GraphFileReader or GraphNeighbors) I could upload it and post the link here to avoid an huge post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are thinking about synchronization errors, I will simplify the error message that you are getting:

> graphs: (boost)adjacency_list.hpp:2679: 
>   boost::out_edges(vertex_descriptor v, adjacency_list& g): Assertion `v.owner == g.processor()' failed.
>
> exit status of rank 1: killed by signal 6

Signal 6 is triggered by `abort()`, which in turn is triggered by the assertion failure above.

I don´t know anything about this graph library, but according to [adjacency_list.hpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/boost/graph/distributed/adjacency_list.hpp) it seems that your processor 1 is calling `out_edges` and passing a vertex `v` that belongs to processor 0.

Comment: Thank you a lot, I'll try to fix that issue!